When formulating the general solutions to a linear diophantine equation $ax + by = c$, does it matter which term is $x$ and which is $y$?
I saw the problem I am working on posted some years ago, and I cannot see how changing the order of the terms can matter, but when applying the general solution after finding one solution, my equations don't make sense. I am guessing this is a trivial mistake, but I cannot seem to find it.
The problem is to find the number of pennies, dimes and quarters equaling 100, and whose worth is exactly $4.99. The set of two equations in three unknowns is straightforward:
$p + d + q = 100$
$p + 10d + 25 q = 499$
Eliminating $p$, I end up with $3d + 8q = 133$, and one solution is found to be $q=2,\ d=39,\ p=59$. So far so good. In the previous answer to this problem, the writer of the answer gave the equation as $8q + 3d = 133$, but I didn't think that the order would matter. But when I apply the theorem for the general solution for this equation, I end up with a nonsense solution:
$d= 39 + 8t$
$q= 2 - 3t$
which leads to a negative value for $q$. If the equation is written as $8q + 3d = 133$, the general solutions are:
$q= 2 + 3t$
$d= 39 - 8t$
which works. What am I not seeing?

To go from one general solution to the other (book vs yours) simply negate $,t.\ $ The general solution is given as $,t,$ ranges over all integers, You need to choose those values that satisfy other constraints of your problem.

You choose the range of $t$ to make both $d$ and $q$ nonnegative.  In the "nonsense solution" you must have $t \le 0$ to make $q \ge 0$.  To have $d \ge 0$ you need $t \ge -4$ so you get five solutions.  In the second solution the range of $t$ is $0 \le t \le 4$ and again you have the same five solutions.
